# Set combobox with long datasource

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, combobox, datasource

Situation: The database access if done actually very fast, over 0.3 seconds, but the lag occurs when assign the datasource to the combo, Freezes over 1 minute.

Problem: How to set combo-box, very long datasource (over 100,000 registries) with NO form freezing.

Actual Code:

```
var q = from c in DataContext.MyTable
select new { Name = c.Name, Id = c.Id };
IQueryable datasource = q;//q.Count()>100,000

this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
this.comboBox1.DataSource = datasource;
```

Technologies: 
I'm using, .Net Framework 4.5.51
With VS2013

Already tried:

A-Use a BackgroundWorker and do the set datasource in the DoWork() method. 
Result: doesn't do nothing, the combo gets no elements.

B- Use a BackGroundWorker and do the set datasource in the RunWorkerCompleted() method. 
Result: It actually work but is like calling the set in the main thread, then also freezes the form.

C- Do the set Datasource in a different thread using BeginInvoke() method

Result: Again the work is done in the main thread and freezes the application

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that the combo is defined within the UI thread. So, adding a big collection to it, will for sure cause some kind of "lag". Is it possible for you to paginate the results of the combo? Or lazy load them? I think you will need to rethink your strategy for filling up this combo.

Comment: I suspect trying to put 100,000 entries into a combo is the problem. I'm sure there's a limit to the amount of data you can put in one of these and in any case are you seriously expecting a user to trawl this amount of entries in a combo?

Comment: You say the database access is very fast, but how do you know that w/o materializing the query, which actually happens when you assign it as data source. Have you measured `var list = q.ToList();` time and then `.DataSource = list` time? If the first part is slow, then you can move it to another thread, or use `async/await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try to remove the combobox from its parent Controls collection, fill the combobox and add it back to parent. Something like that:

```
        var parent = comboBox.Parent;
        parent.Controls.Remove(comboBox);
        comboBox.DataSource = ds;
        parent.Controls.Add(comboBox);
```

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but helped me with no messing with the main thread and the set the datasource in a separate thread while showing a progress bar...
But after some talking finally i convinced my client not to have a combo with that extra long information and did a search form to manage the issue. Thanks everyone